# Starting video failed when using webcam in Big Blue Button ubuntu 18.04

Tags: webcam, bigbluebutton

When trying to give access to my webcam (VGA Single Chip via USB) in BBB, an error appears.
But the camera is OK e. g. it works in GUVCView and the command

```
lsusb
```

gives

```
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 093a:2603 Pixart Imaging, Inc. PAC7312 Camera
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
[...]
```

When choosing the integrated Cam in BBB, this works.
[image]

Comment: In these cases, it would be interesting to look at your browser developer console. The console logs especially, would give some debugs that might tell us what happened. Have you been using this camera with other web-based visio conferencing solutions (Jitsi, Zoom, Google Hangouts, ....), are we sure the issue is related to BigBlueButton?

Comment: @SYN I am not sure that it is related to BigBlueButton. But the webcam is ~10 years old. I will replaced it.

Comment: webcam may be fine, could be something wrong with your browser, your network, ... checking the logs on both your browser console and the bigbluebutton instance is the way to figure out what's going on.